# How do I zip a folder using the command line while maintaining its file structure?

Tags: terminal, zip

For example, if I want to zip `/Users/admin/Downloads/Backup`, and I am at `/Users/admin/`, I could:

`zip -r downloads.zip /Users/admin/Downloads/Backup`

and if I unzip `downloads.zip` I would get a Users folder and have a Users => admin => Downloads => Backup structure.

This is particularly undesirable behavior if I want to create an installation zip file for TWRP.

So instead I will have to:

`cd /Users/admin/Downloads/Backup; zip -r /Users/admin/downloads.zip .; cd /Users/admin/`

This doesn’t feel like what a pro would do.

What can I do to zip a folder while maintaining its file structure?

Comment: A pro would do that but perhaps put it all in a script so do't ned to type as much.They would use pushd/popd instead of cd so the directory you return to is where you were when you called the script - and not ~/admin everytime.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `zip` and not `tar` with `gzip` compression?  It's much easier, but you might have a specific need.

Comment: @Allan TWRP doesn't support tar.

Comment: Crossposted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1091695/158442

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really what you want, as you may use the command line or a script but there are options.

First, don't supply the entire path for the archive

```
 cd folder; zip -r ../zipped_dir.zip *
```

Or for a script you might use cd or pushd and popd to move into the directory that will be the root of the archive before issuing the zip command. How you do this exactly will depend on how the script knows what to zip up. But, if for example you want admin/Downloads/Backup/folder zipped with internal paths of just ./folder, you'd need to do this:

```
pushd /Users/admin/Downloads/Backup
zip -r /path/to/out.zip ./folder/
popd
```

That will result in your out.zip containing the relative paths you want.

Answer (score 1):

A "pro" would first read the manual. Now, the `zip` manual is full of cruft but long into the read you'll find- " zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).". Further into the read you will find an option to remove all paths in your zip archive but that is not a great idea, since you can create a "bomb" archive that will pollute the directory in which it is extracted. It's best to contain your archive within its own directory.

```
cd /Users/admin/Downloads
zip -r downloads Backup
mv -- downloads.zip some/other/location
cd -
```

- First we change directory to /Users/admin/Downloads
- We name the archive (downloads) and .zip will be added to the archive name
- We recurse through the Backup directory adding all files including the parent directory to the archive
- move the zip archive to another location
- Finally, we call the environment variable OLDPWD to get back to the original directory- `cd -`